# Search for Specific Files in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My VBA code below searches for all files in my Drive C: and list them in Sheet(1). Now, I am tasked to find specific .txt files only. I have tried modifying the code but to no success. I was thinking it has something to do with the ObjFile.

```
    Sub ListAllFiles()

Dim ObjFSO As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim objFolder As Scripting.Folder

Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder("C:\")


Call getfiledetails(objFolder)

End Sub

Function getfiledetails(objFolder As Scripting.Folder)

Dim objFile As Scripting.File
Dim nextRow As Long
Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder

nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
On Error Resume Next
    Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name
    Cells(nextRow, 2) = objFile.Path
    Cells(nextRow, 3) = objFile.Type
    Cells(nextRow, 4) = objFile.DateCreated
    Cells(nextRow, 5) = objFile.DateLastModified
    nextRow = nextRow + 1

Next objFile

For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
Call getfiledetails(objSubFolder)

Next

End Function
```

Any Help would be appreciated

Comment: Use DIR as shown [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba/10382861#10382861)  Change `StrFile = Dir("c:\testfolder\*test*")` to suit your need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DIR` probably has a slight performance advantage, but if you wanted to use your existing code then the following tweak to the `getfiledetails` sub would give you the desired output:

```
Function getfiledetails(objFolder As Scripting.Folder)

    Dim objFile As Scripting.File
    Dim nextRow As Long
    Dim objSubFolder As Scripting.Folder

    nextRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    On Error Resume Next

    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        If objFile.Type = "Text Document" Then
            Cells(nextRow, 1) = objFile.Name
            Cells(nextRow, 2) = objFile.Path
            Cells(nextRow, 3) = objFile.Type
            Cells(nextRow, 4) = objFile.DateCreated
            Cells(nextRow, 5) = objFile.DateLastModified
            nextRow = nextRow + 1
        End If

    Next objFile

    For Each objSubFolder In objFolder.SubFolders
        Call getfiledetails(objSubFolder)
    Next

End Function
```

This can be added to, if you wanted more than one document type, such as..

```
If objFile.Type = "Microsoft Word Document" Or objFile.Type = "Text Document" Then
```

Comment: Sir, this works like a charm! THANK YOU!!!! I will check the DIR Function and follow your suggestion. Once again, Thank you!

Comment: The reason I think that `DIR` might give you a performance boost is that the routine I've tweaked there is reading every file into an object and then examining the `.Type`. Using a `DIR` command such as `x = DIR(folder & "/*.txt")` does the filtering for you before hand. Both methods have their uses. Also, @Siddharth generally knows what he's talking about so if he's suggesting `DIR` then he'll have a very good reason.

Comment: Nice one, CLR!!